# Angular mat select

Tags: angular, typescript

When the selected index is 0 which is "Same Value" I wanted to pass a value of 0 and not the text "Same Value" . How are we going manipulate the array to do that ? Thanks.

Cause I need to show the "Same Value" text (please check the image) as option in the UI and when user select it then its value would be 0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vnR9.png)

#HTML COMPONENT

```
<div fxFlex fxLayout="row">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-4" fxFlex>
            <mat-label>Select Month</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="month_" required>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let month of months;" [value]="month">
                {{month}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

#TS Component

```
export class MonthSelectorComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  public months     = ["Same Value", 1, 2, 3, 6, 12];

.................
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have the array of month having the objects mentioning the value and the name.

So update your array of month as the below code:

```
 public months     = ["Same Value", 1, 2, 3, 6, 12];
  public months     = [{name:"Same Value",value:"0"},
                       {name:"1",value:"1"},
                       {name:"2",value:"2"},{name:"3",value:"3"},{name:"6",value:"6"}, {name:"12",value:"12"}];
```

And your HTML code should be updated by the following lines of code:

```
<div fxFlex fxLayout="row">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-4" fxFlex>
        <mat-label>Select Month</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="month_" required>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let month of months;" [value]="month.value">
            {{month.name}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```